# How JPA saves OneToMany Object graph

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

How does JPA saves OneToMany object graph when entity on Many side is already present in database. Does it query table for entity on 'Many' side to find the primary key so it can be inserted in Entity on 'One' side?

E.g.
Employee ---* Projects

There is a webpage where you one needs to provide employee details and then add projects one by one. Say employee details provided on the page and 2 projects details provided and added and this object graph is saved. Now when second employee details are provided and a project detail is provided that is same as the one already in database, and this graph is saved, would JPA implementation in this case query 'Many' side of table with all the fields from Project in where clause to see if entity is already present? And if yes then fetch it and provide id to Employee instead of inserting Project in database again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would JPA implementation in this case query 'Many' side of table with all the fields from Project in where clause to see if entity is already present?

No. What identifies an entity is its ID. Nothing else. BTW, if it did that, you wouldn't have a OneToMany association anymore, since the same project would become linked to two employees.